# Docker/zsh command unable to find existing directory on mac

Tags: linux, docker, shell, unix, docker-compose

I am running the following command:

```
docker run --name axonserver -p 8024:8024 -p 8124:8124 -v
"/users/shahidsarwar/docker-data/data":/data -v
"/users/shahidsarwar/docker-data/eventdata":/eventdata -v
 "/users/shahidsarwar/docker-data/config":/config axoniq/axonserver
```

but I am getting this error on my mac:

```
flag needs an argument: 'v' in -v
See 'docker run --help'.
zsh: no such file or directory: /users/shahidsarwar/docker-data/data:/data
zsh: no such file or directory: /users/shahidsarwar/docker-data/eventdata:/eventdata
zsh: no such file or directory: /users/shahidsarwar/docker-data/config:/config
```

what is the issue?

Comment: In a shell script, each line normally consists of a single command. Hence your `docker` command ends in `-v` without argument. Writing a command to span several lines is possible, but error prone; I recommend writing everything in a single line.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the escapes for the newlines

```
docker run --name axonserver -p 8024:8024 -p 8124:8124 -v \
"/users/shahidsarwar/docker-data/data":/data -v \
"/users/shahidsarwar/docker-data/eventdata":/eventdata -v \
 "/users/shahidsarwar/docker-data/config":/config axoniq/axonserver
```

otherwise they are interpreted as different commands.